# Which files are mandatory to run appium on an Android 3rd party device?

Tags: java, android, automation, ui-automation, appium

I use appium for the first time. I want to run a simple automation on a 3rd party installed app. I want to configure the appium server for that specific app.

I have few questions:

1. Which fields are mandatory?
2. I have to fill them manually? because my Android is plugged in to the mac,
   and yet I cannot autocomplete names.
3. How can I easily find the desired app apk path and it's launch activity (I guess after double clicking the apk?)

[image]

### Update:

I now get the following error:

doesn't work.

new console opened:

```
➜  ~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Doctor:

Running Android Checks

```
✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to "/Users/eladb/MyWorkspace2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/"
✔ JAVA_HOME is set to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home."
✔ ADB exists at /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/adb
✔ Android exists at /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/android
✔ Emulator exists at /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/emulator
✔ Android Checks were successful.

✔ All Checks were successful
➜  ~
```

and yet appium says:

```
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.927 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"}}}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.grindrapp.android","appActivity":".activity.SplashActivity","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"10.0.0.9:5555"}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)

info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device

info: [debug] Creating new appium session e232fa9d-a70c-4de9-84e7-d86441cc9dc6

info: Starting android appium

info: [debug] Getting Java version

info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

info: [debug] Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:1040:17
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:735:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?)","origValue":"Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 87.838 ms - 222 

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
```

I'm using appium 1.3.5

Comment: I posted a possible solution for this at:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720260/error-could-not-get-the-java-version-is-java-installed/28778459#28778459][1]
Please give me an upvote there if it works for you. Thanks!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720260/error-could-not-get-the-java-version-is-java-installed/28778459#28778459

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the following fields:

1. App path
2. package name
3. launch activity(you can ask your developers to find the launch activity of the apk file)
4. device
5. SDK path
6. Bootstrap port
7. Server Address(by default 127.0.0.1)
8. Port(by default it runs on 4723)

If you don't want to mention these in the Appium, you can also mention it in your scripts by using capabilities class.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "something");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "something");
            capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
```

Comment: can you please tell how can I fix this?