# Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?

Tags: android, testing, ui-automation, appium

I run Appium server:

```
➜  ~  appium    
info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.5 (REV a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.grindrapp.android","appActivity":".activity.SplashActivity","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"10.0.0.9:5555"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 090abe0c-36d9-4f9b-987a-f3b665045928
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
info: [debug] Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:1040:17
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:735:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?)","origValue":"Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 316.738 ms - 222 


^C
➜  ~  echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_76.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I try to run this code to post to Appium server:

```
public class AndroidTest {

    private AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
//        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
//        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "../../../data/app/");
//        File app = new File(appDir, "Facebook.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","10.0.0.9:5555");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        //capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getCanonicalPath());

        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.grindrapp.android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activity.SplashActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
```

but as you can see I get this error:

```
info: [debug] Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
```

how can I fix this?

I'm trying to automatically open an app which i downloaded from the google play and I don't have its apk.

Comment: This is a known issue with appium 1.3.5.  According to other posts that I have read, new code was added to android-commons.js in recent releases.  This code sometimes works and other times it fails.  Your stack trace is specific in that it occurs on line 1040:17.  Please post the code from android-commons.js(before and after that line) as it appears that is the request for finding the java version.

Comment: also, your JAVA_HOME path looks unusual.  Most folks have a path that ends at the jdk directory.  I know it sounds stupid, but what does the contents/home directory contain?  And what does java -version return?

Comment: where does this file reside? `Please post the code from android-commons.js`

Comment: downgrading to appium 1.3.4 will fix this?

Comment: the location for android-commons.js is right there in your stack trace: info: [debug] Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:1040:17

Comment: I have tried also java 18:

    ➜  ~  java -version   
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.proxyHost=cache.c.google.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
    java version "1.8.0_31"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b15)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the final solution for your problem.

As always, make a backup copy of the file before editing.

Edit the file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js

In the else if(stderr) branch around line 1034:

```
else if (stderr) {
        var firstLine = stderr.split("\n")[0];
        if (new RegExp("java version").test(firstLine)) {
          javaVersion = firstLine.split(" ")[2].replace(/"/g, '');
        }
      }
```

replace the code to read:

```
else if (stderr){
    if(new RegExp("java version").test(stderr)){
      var regex = "java version \"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+";
      var stderrstring = '' + stderr + '';
      var regmatch = stderrstring.match(regex);
      javaVersion = '' + regmatch + ''   //convert object to string
      javaVersion.replace(/"/g,'');
    }
}
```

The code should work with a regular java version response message plus the one that you are receiving.

Comment: will try. but how come downgrading to appium 1.3.4 didn't help? Is this code change needed to every user? It's strange it happens only to me. no?

Comment: thanks for the help. now I get: info: [debug] Getting Java version
error: Unhandled error: ReferenceError: match is not defined
    at /usr/local/avm/versions/1.3.5/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:1039:26
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:735:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12) context: [POST /wd/hub/session

Comment: I think this means that it views the stderr as an object and not a string.  Objects dont have a match method.    So,  var stderrstring = '' + stderr + ''; //those are tick marks, not a quotation mark.  var regmatch = stderrstring.match(regex);

Comment: I edited the code above to convert stderr to stderrstring.  There is one line added and then a change in the line that starts with var regmatch.  Other people are having this problem in different packages that also use this code.  One did reference a JAVA_OPTIONS problem.  The code as originally written assumes a standard java -version response.  Once you get to using more advanced environment variables, problems result.

Comment: works. just change to `javaVersion = '' + regmatch + ''`

Comment: Excellent!   On to the next issue.

Comment: actually I have a small (un)related q. now after the driver is initialized how do I make it wait till certain activity is on? (and how do I make it wait if it's during runtime not just start up)

Answer (score 0):

The file is located here:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js

The code we are concerned with starting at line 1029 is:

```
androidCommon.getJavaVersion = function (cb) {
    exec("java -version", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      var javaVersion = null;
      if (err) {
        return cb(new Error("'java -version' failed. " + err));
      } else if (stderr) {
        var firstLine = stderr.split("\n")[0];
        if (new RegExp("java version").test(firstLine)) {
          javaVersion = firstLine.split(" ")[2].replace(/"/g, '');
        }
      }
      if (javaVersion === null) {
        return cb(new Error("Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?"));
      }
      return cb(null, javaVersion);
    });
};
```

I am unable to test this on my system, but I think that a successful execution of java -version would return its response on stdout and not stderr.  I would change the code to provide more information as to what is happening and help debug it.

You are getting the JavaVersion = null message at the end of the listing which means that there is nothing returned in err and parsing of stderr is not setting JavaVersion.  It does not tell you if there is anything in stderr nor does it even look at stdout.

Here is a revised code listing.  If the output is indeed returned on stderr, the code will now at least print it out so you can see what is returned.  I added the same code branch for stdout as it was not checked at all.

```
androidCommon.getJavaVersion = function (cb) {
exec("java -version", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    var javaVersion = null;
    var firstLine = null;

    if (err) {
      return cb(new Error("'java -version' failed. " + err));
    } else if (stderr) {
        firstLine = stderr.split("\n")[0];

        if (new RegExp("java version").test(firstLine)) {
          javaVersion = firstLine.split(" ")[2].replace(/"/g, '');
        }else{
          return cb(new Error("Java version stderr string parse error: " + stderr));
        }
    } else if(stdout){
            firstLine = stdout.split("\n")[0];

        if (new RegExp("java version").test(firstLine)) {
          javaVersion = firstLine.split(" ")[2].replace(/"/g, '');
        }else{
          return cb(new Error("Java version stdout string parse error: " + stdout));
        }       
    }   

    if (javaVersion === null) {
      return cb(new Error("Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?"));
    }
      return cb(null, javaVersion);
});
}
```

So:

1. make a backup copy of android-commons.js
2. make the code change and give it a try.

This might work as written or the error messages will tell you what is being returned.

Comment: downgrading to appium 1.3.4 will fix this?

Comment: after changing android-common.js, I get this log:

➜  ~  appium          

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Java version stderr string parse error: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.proxyHost=cache.c.google.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Update 2

I have also tried to use appium 1.3.4 and got the same error:

➜  ~  avm use 1.3.4
info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.4 
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
info: [debug] Error: Could not get the Java version. Is Java installed?
    at

Comment: when you run java -version on the command line, is the output the same as the stderr string parse error message?  I saw a post where someone said that the internal appium results did not match the command line results.

Answer (score 0):

The code in android-common.js is looking for the java version number on the first line.
I had the similar issue, but my java -version returns result as

```
[~]$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

So I simply changed the code in android-common.js to split second line instead of first line

```
firstLine = stderr.split("\n")[0]; -> firstLine = stderr.split("\n")[1]
```